# jQuery works in browser, but not in an android emulator

Tags: jquery, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm a noob in hybrid development and I'm trying to use jQuery in my App.

I'm surprised that the my code is working fine in the browser, but not in an android emulator and I don't quite understand the reason for that.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/onsenui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/onsen-css-  
  components.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sliding_menu.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-onsenui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>   

</head>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("h6").click(function(){
       $(this).hide();
     });
   });
</script> 
<body>

<h6>If you click on me, I will disappear.</h6>
<h6>Click me away!</h6>
<h6>Click me too!</h6>

</body>
</html>
```

**Logs Output :**

[image]

Cant understand what may be the reason...

Comment: please use android studio and debug your app it might show you errors android app is facing

Comment: @AtulNar there is no error I have seen the error log

Comment: @AshishShukla can you place some alert in document ready function and see whether jquery document ready is fired properly in device?

Comment: @AshishShukla where are you checking error logs ? can you post console logs from logcat !

Comment: @AtulNar I have added the logs

Comment: where's the index.js file ?

Comment: @Kirankumar  that error is for some other file which executes on start

Comment: Ok, so please have a look created jsfiddle and check if there is any conflict issue happens between all js

Comment: I have added console.log inside ready function but no output

Comment: were you ever able to get a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome://inspect/#devices and open the inspector for your APP.

Then find if the jquery.min.js file exists in Sources,

Type $("h6").hide(); in console and execute it, check does it work or is there any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

Please try removing all the js and set only jQuery js may be they were conflicted But it is working fine with your browser so here is a jsFiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fqhj3j2j/), check and compare

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <h6>If you click on me, I will disappear.</h6>
 <h6>Click me away!</h6>
 <h6>Click me too!</h6>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h6").click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have removed all files except jquery js but still same

Comment: Set alerts after document ready and then h6 on click and check if which alerts displays